# How to show trailing "%" symbol?

Tags: acumatica

In SO Line's discount pct column, i'd like to show trailing "%" in it.

[image]

I tried to set the display format to "P" but it was a disaster :)

[image]

Because the actual value is the percentage rate in the database, it unnecessarily multiply it with 100.

[image]

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `DisplayFormat` to `0.00'%'`

[image]

and as a result you will get the following:

[image]

If you don't want to show the decimal part use `0'%'`.

UPDATE

You may use `#,##0.00%` Display Format.