# Decimals displayed on the POLine and SOLine Details Grid

Tags: acumatica

How do I control the number of decimals displayed on the POLine and/or SOLine Details Grid?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49316031/how-to-show-trailing-symbol/49317023#49317023. You can set Display format and show as many decimals as you need.

Comment: Is this a question related to the use of Acumatica (where to define decimal places) or are you trying to change the displayed/rounded decimal settings in a grid or dac programmatically?

Comment: I would prefer the synatx to Override Attributes on Screen level.

[PXDBCurrency(typeof(Search<CommonSetup.decPlPrcCst>), typeof(POLine.curyInfoID), typeof(POLine.unitCost))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Unit Cost", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.0")]